# Adjusting data for measurement errors

Tags: multiple-comparisons, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have approximately 500,000 data points that were mechanically measured over about 2000 days.  The equipment is manually set up each day, which likely induces some error.  What I am attempting to do is use a linear mixed effects model to estimate the fixed effect of each day's potential measurement error while accounting for other known random effects and covariates, and then adjust that day's measurement based on the estimated effect.  I am using lme4 in R.  Given that lme4 cannot estimate fixed effects with so many levels, I have broken my data into 50 day chunks.  I then compare each day to 50 other randomly selected days that I treat as one level.

My first question is: is this a reasonable thing to do?  The only other thread I could find dealing with such an issue regarding lm4 suggested that the author probably didn't actually want to estimate a model with so many levels.  Given that each day could theoretically have a different fixed measurement error based on how the equipment is set up though, it seems to make sense to me in this case.

My second question is: assuming I have reasonable estimates of each day's fixed effect, how would I go about adjusting my data?  If I was just trying to determine which day's effects are likely to be significant I would perform some adjustment for multiple-comparisons.  As I see it, I am trying to minimize the error over two sources - the measurement error from the equipment, and the error in estimating each fixed effect.